# Using getDerivedStateFromProps to fetch API data is causing the component to render many times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to fetch some data from an API call. I am using `getDerivedStateFromProps`, `componentDidMount,`shouldComponentUpdate`and`componentDidUpdate`.

I am doing it like this because I need `userToken` which comes from `userToken: store.signinScreen.userToken` to be there before the call of the function `GetPassengersData` which needs `userToken` to get the data from the API.

This is the whole component:

```
// imports

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };

  state = {
    error: false,
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.userToken !== state.userToken) {
      return { userToken: props.userToken };
    }
    return null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.GetPassengersData();
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(prevProps, state) {
    return this.props !== prevProps;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { error } = this.state;
    if (!error) {
      this.GetPassengersData();
    }
  }

  GetPassengersData = async () => {
    const { passengersDataActionHandler, userToken } = this.props;
    if (userToken && userToken !== null) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          'http://myAPI/public/api/getPassengers',
          {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`,
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          },
        );
        const responseJson = await response.json();
        if (has(responseJson, 'error')) {
          this.setState({ error: true });
          Alert.alert('Error', 'Please check your credentials.');
        } else {
          passengersDataActionHandler(responseJson.success.data);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        this.setState({ error: true });
        Alert.alert(
          'Error',
          'There was an error with your request, please try again later.',
        );
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <TabView style={styles.container} />;
  }
}

HomeScreen.defaultProps = {
  userToken: null,
};

HomeScreen.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired,
  passengersDataActionHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  userToken: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string]),
};

export default compose(
  connect(
    store => ({
      userToken: store.signinScreen.userToken,
      passengersData: store.homeScreen.passengersData,
    }),
    dispatch => ({
      passengersDataActionHandler: token => {
        dispatch(passengersDataAction(token));
      },
    }),
  ),
)(HomeScreen);
```

With this implementation, the component renders many times so it breaks the application.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You `setState` in `GetPassengersData()`. if `state` updated then `componentDidUpdate()` will exec. This is inf loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you don't need to store `userToken` in state since you are not modifying it locally and hence you don't need `getDerivedStateFromProps`

Secondly, you need to trigger API call in componentDidUpdate only on as prop change and not directly without a check otherwise, the setState inside the API success or error will cause the component to re-render calling `componentDidUpdate` again and thus calling the API again resulting in a infinite loop

Third, the check inside shouldComponentUpdate comparing props is not exactly correct since nestedObjects props will give a false negative result and also if you write a deep equality check for props, the component won't re-render if the state changes.

```
// imports

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };

  state = {
    error: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.GetPassengersData();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.userToken !== this.props.userToken) {
      this.GetPassengersData();
    }
  }

  GetPassengersData = async () => {
    const { passengersDataActionHandler, userToken } = this.props;
    if (userToken && userToken !== null) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          'http://myAPI/public/api/getPassengers',
          {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`,
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          },
        );
        const responseJson = await response.json();
        if (has(responseJson, 'error')) {
          this.setState({ error: true });
          Alert.alert('Error', 'Please check your credentials.');
        } else {
          passengersDataActionHandler(responseJson.success.data);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        this.setState({ error: true });
        Alert.alert(
          'Error',
          'There was an error with your request, please try again later.',
        );
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <TabView style={styles.container} />;
  }
}

HomeScreen.defaultProps = {
  userToken: null,
};

HomeScreen.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired,
  passengersDataActionHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  userToken: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string]),
};

export default compose(
  connect(
    store => ({
      userToken: store.signinScreen.userToken,
      passengersData: store.homeScreen.passengersData,
    }),
    dispatch => ({
      passengersDataActionHandler: token => {
        dispatch(passengersDataAction(token));
      },
    }),
  ),
)(HomeScreen);
```